# Detecting wireless card in asus a6k

Tags: wireless

I am trying ubuntu 12.04 (live from USB) in my asus a6k. It does not detect the wireless card. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+T, run `lspci | grep -i net` and edit your question to include that command's output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the unlucky owners of that computer... Its wireless chip is a Broadcom 43xx.
You can follow these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access